# ServiceStack not sending cookies when run from Mono

Tags: c#, linux, cookies, mono, servicestack

This is a problem that seems to exist only in Mono (Version 2.10 in my case) running on Ubuntu. My console program runs as intended on Windows, even when using Mono on Windows.

I have a service on our API that requires authentication. The client accessing it does authentication as usual and hangs onto the ss-id to later put into a cookie and add to the JsonServiceClient cookie container. I am calling JsonServiceClient in this way:

```
internal class ApiClient
{
    // Service client
    private JsonServiceClient _ServiceClient;
    internal JsonServiceClient ServiceClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ServiceClient == null)
            {
                _ServiceClient = new JsonServiceClient(globals.ApiUrl);
            }

            var CookieQuery = (from c in globals.AuthCookieContainer
                               where c.Name == "ss-id"
                               where !c.Expired
                               select c);

            if (CookieQuery.Count() > 0)
            {
                _ServiceClient.CookieContainer.Add(CookieQuery.FirstOrDefault());
            }

            return _ServiceClient; 
        }
        set
        {
            _ServiceClient = value; 
        }
    }
```

Easy enough. The intent there is to simply return the existing service client or a new one with an auth token already included. It seems to work just fine everywhere else I'm using it.

To use the client elsewhere in my program to grab some object from the API server I call something like this:

```
return ClientClass.ServiceClient.Get(new ServiceModel.DueRequest()).Result;
```

As mentioned above, executing this console app runs as expected on Windows and Mono for Windows. The client is called, goes out to the server and grabs a list of objects as expected.

On Linux however I try to run the app using "~$ mono MyApp.exe /arg1 /arg2 /arg3" it responds with a 302 trying to redirect me to a place to login. Naturally this indicates that ServiceStack was never told about my existing session for this particular request. So... Just to be sure I had closer look at the machine hosting our API(Itself hosted with Apache/mod_mono) it appears as if the initial authentication (using credentialsauthprovider) is working as expected, I'm getting back an SS-ID to use, etc.

Digging deeper I had a look at the headers being sent to Apache. When executing this console app from Windows a cookie with the ss-id is included in the request for DueRequest (shown above) as it should be. **However when running the exact same executable with Mono on Linux, the cookie is absent.** Again, this is running the exact same version of the executable and ServiceStack DLLs.

I would have to guess that this is more of a problem with Mono, I'm just wondering if anybody has experienced this behavior before when using Mono on Linux / ServiceStack together.

**Further info**

To confirm that a cookie is not being sent, I went ahead and fired up TCPdump on the API server itself (The one running Apache/mod_mono):

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -s 1024 -l -A port 80 | egrep -w 'cookie|Cookie'
```

When making a request from a client that is "working", I see:

```
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=xZ/1TG8ED1dhxntBOPLA; path=/; expires=Sat, 04 Feb 2034 20:48:09 GMT; HttpOnly
Cookie: ss-id=xZ/1TG8ED1dhxntBOPLA
```

When running with Mono from a Linux terminal:

```
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=TTIJ2tYOXjRwUwCfv/sn; path=/; expires=Sat, 04 Feb 2034 20:49:17 GMT; HttpOnly
```

The server is obviously responding with a cookie... but in the case of the second example the client is never sending one.

Comment: Sean did the test application I added work for you?

Comment: It did not. When I move back towards this part of my project I will respond with what part broke

Comment: I do my deployment testing over SSH tunnels and I have noticed that cookies aren't received over the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

I use Mono all the time, and don't have this issue. I created a fully working console application *(below)* and tested on Mono 2.10.6 and Mono 3.2.6. *ServiceStack v4.0.9*

I would suggest you try the application and see if it passes.

### Test Application:

```cs
using System;
using ServiceStack;

namespace TestCookies
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Very basic console host
            var appHost = new AppHost(500);
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start("http://*:9000/");

            // Make client request
            var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:9000");
            Console.WriteLine("Has cookie? {0}", client.Get(new HasCookieRequest()));
            client.Get(new SetCookieRequest());
            Console.WriteLine("Set cookie? {0}", client.CookieContainer.Count > 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Has cookie? {0}", client.Get(new HasCookieRequest()));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase
    {
        public AppHost(int poolSize) : base("Cookie Test Service", poolSize, typeof(CookieTestService).Assembly) {}

        public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
        {
            Config = new HostConfig {
                DebugMode = true,
            };
        }
    }

    [Route("/SetCookie","GET")]
    public class SetCookieRequest : IReturnVoid {}

    [Route("/HasCookie","GET")]
    public class HasCookieRequest : IReturn<bool> {}

    public class CookieTestService : Service
    {
        public void Get(SetCookieRequest request)
        {
            Response.SetCookie("ss-id","1234567890",DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
        }

        public bool Get(HasCookieRequest request)
        {
            return Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("ss-id");
        }
    }
}
```

### Expected Result:

> Has cookie? False
>   Set cookie? True
>   Has cookie? True

---

As an aside just an observation from your code *Slightly off topic. Hope you don't find it cheeky to point this out*. You would be better changing this:

```
var CookieQuery = (from c in globals.AuthCookieContainer
                   where c.Name == "ss-id"
                   where !c.Expired
                   select c);

if (CookieQuery.Count() > 0)
{
    _ServiceClient.CookieContainer.Add(CookieQuery.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Into this:

```
var cookie = (from c in globals.AuthCookieContainer
              where c.Name == "ss-id"
              where !c.Expired
              select c).FirstOrDefault();

if (cookie!=null)
{
    _ServiceClient.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
}
```

When you call `.Count()` the `CookieQuery` will be evaluated, then when you call `FirstOrDefault()` it will be evaluated again. The second way doesn't, it is more efficient. It's very minor, but when I started using Linq I did the same. ;)